# Overview of unsaved file when quitting gVim

Tags: gvim, quit

When quitting gVim by closing the gVim windows I get a warning message asking me if I want to save my change or not (in case there are unsaved buffers):

[image]

gVim doesn't show unsaved buffers.
It is difficult to take the right decision without seeing the name or the content of the files.
gVim only gives the name of the first unsaved buffer.

Is there a way to have an overview of the unsaved buffers when the dialog is shown?

Comment: Not "when the dialog is shown". I was about to suggest doing something on `VimLeavePre` but it appears that the dialog is triggered before. I think it's the kind of thing that has to be implemented fully at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :-) Could you precise what you mean implemented at runtime? Do you mean: "by changing the code of Vim"?

Comment: I mean by writing the logic yourself, in vimscript.

Comment: But which event can I use if VimLeavPre is not triggered before the dialog?

Comment: You're sure gVim only shows the name of the *first* unsaved buffer? If I create 3 sample files and quit gVim, I am asked for each of them. Maybe I misunderstand the question. FWIW, I usually *cancel* and review my open buffers.

Comment: I'm asked for each but one by one without gVim showing the content of the corresponding buffer. Most of the time the unsaved buffers are working buffers for which I'm willing to discard the changes. I would like to asses that quickly and quit instead of reviewing each without seeing the content of the buffer. I suppose there is there something that could be improved :-)